# Where can i find a good web to obtain UAPROF's?

Tags: mobile, uaprof

i'm trying to find a good UAPROF website but only i can see that http://www.uaprof.com/ . I need UAPROFS of HTC and in that web a lot of links are broken. Do you know another web or resource to find that UAPROFS ?

Thank you in advance for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Open Mobile Alliance validator](http://validator.openmobilealliance.org/) keeps [links to validated profiles](http://validator.openmobilealliance.org/cgi/validation/profiles.html). However the manufacturers do remove old profiles, or in some cases the manufacturers no longer exist, which is probably why you are seeing broken links at uaprof.com.

Google is another good source of profiles by searching for ["uaprof filetype:xml"](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=uaprof%20filetype%3axml%20&oq=uaprof%20filetype%3axml%20&sugexp=chrome,mod=5&sourceid=chrome&client=ubuntu&channel=cs&ie=UTF-8&num=100&complete=0) and ["uaprof filetype:rdf"](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=uaprof%20filetype%3axml%20&oq=uaprof%20filetype%3ardf%20&sugexp=chrome,mod=5&sourceid=chrome&client=ubuntu&channel=cs&ie=UTF-8&num=100&complete=0#num=100&hl=en&client=ubuntu&hs=Yrh&tbo=d&channel=cs&complete=0&q=uaprof%20filetype%3ardf&oq=uaprof%20filetype%3ardf&gs_l=serp.3...4364.5213.0.5300.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0.les;..0.0...1c.1.2.serp.7dk5Af9xGWk&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&bvm=bv.41867550,d.dGI&fp=8a583eaadc0c82e3&biw=1366&bih=632).

Alternatively check out [WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/). This is not UAProf, but the data is derived from UAProf, it's XML so it is easier to process, and it is curated so it will not have the same problems.

There are more UAProf resources at the [DELI website](http://delicon.sourceforge.net/).